# js file does not work in iMacros why

Tags: javascript, playback, imacros

i have a javascript codes which first works in imacros but now it's does not work. Loop does not play. Can anyone tell me why this will be happened. Below is the codes.

Please solve this problem why now this javascript does not work in the imacros.

```
   var i, retcode;
   \var report;
   var macrolist = new Array();

   /* Standard Demo Macros  */
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/FillForm.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Frame.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Filter.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Tabs.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Javascript-Dialogs.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/SlideShow.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/TagPosition.iim");
   /* Macros that save something and/or create logs  */
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Download.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/SaveAs.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/SavePDF.iim");
   /* Macros that create reports */
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Stopwatch.iim");
   /* Macros that extract information */
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/ExtractAndFill.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/Extract.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/ExtractURL.iim");
   macrolist.push("Demo-Firefox/ExtractRelative.iim");



   iimDisplay("Start Self Test");

   report  =  "Self-Test Report\n\n";

   for (i = 0; i < macrolist.length; i++) {
iimDisplay("Step "+(i+1)+" of "+macrolist.length + "\nMacro: "+macrolist[i]);
retcode = iimPlay(macrolist[i]);
report += macrolist[i];
if (retcode < 0) {
    report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
} else {
    report += ": OK";
    /* display the FIRST extracted item in report*/
    s = iimGetLastExtract(1);
    if ( s != "" )  report += ", Extract: "+s;
}
report += "\n";
   }
   iimDisplay("Test complete");

   alert ( report );
```

Comment: Use the latest version of iMacros. Now it can show you the line of the code where is the error located.

Answer (score 0):

try to instal latest firefox 19 and reinstal imacros with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, retcode;
   \var report;
   var macrolist = new Array();
```

var report; has the \ and it breaks your code.

Comment: No problem. If that was the issue, accept the answer and close the question. I do believe that was your problem, your script worked fine for me, once I removed the "\" that is